# Implement a rounded tab shape

Tags: css

we got a design to implement but I can't find a way to do it in CSS:

[image]

I succeed to do the triangle on right with a css trick (`border-bottom`, `border-right` & `solid transparent`).
But I do not find a way to do a "curved" triangle like on the picture.

I suppose their is no way to do it in CSS and this will require an SVG ?